# What is the best way to test Controllers and Services with JUnit?

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have this Spring MVC controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo")
public class FooController {

    @Inject
    private FooService fooService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "foo/new")
    public final String add(final ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute(fooService.createFoo());
        return "foo/detail";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "foo/{id}")
    public final String detail(final ModelMap model, @PathVariable long id) {
        model.addAttribute(fooService.findById(id));
        return "foo/detail";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="foo/update", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public final String save(@Valid @ModelAttribute final Foo foo, final BindingResult result, final SessionStatus status,
            final RedirectAttributes ra, final HttpServletRequest request) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "foo/detail";
        }

        fooService.save(foo);
        status.setComplete();
        Message.success(ra, "message.ok");

        return "redirect:foo/list";
    }


    @RequestMapping( value= "/foo/delete/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String delete(@PathVariable final Long id, final SessionStatus status, final RedirectAttributes ra, final HttpServletRequest request){

        if (fooService.findByIdWithOtherFoos(id).getOtherFoos().isEmpty()) {
            fooService.delete(id);
            status.setComplete();
            MessageHelper.success(ra, "message.sucess");
        } else {
            Message.error(ra, "message.error");
        }

        return "redirect:foo/list";
    }
}
```

And this Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {

    @Inject
    private fooRepository fooRepo;

    @Override
    public final Foo createFoo() {
        return new Foo();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public final void save(final Foo foo) {

        if (foo.getId() == null) {
            foo.setDate(new Date());
        }

        fooRepo.save(foo);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public final void delete(final Long id) {
        fooRepo.delete(id);
    }

    @Override
    public final Foo findById(final Long id) {
        return fooRepo.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Foo findByIdWithOtherFoos(Long id) {
        Foo foo = fooRepo.findOne(id);
        Hibernate.initialize(foo.getOtherFoos());
        return foo;
    }

    @Override
    public final Page<Foo> findAll(final Pageable pageable) {
        return fooRepo.findAll(pageable);
    }

    @Override
    public final Page<Foo> find(final String filter, final Pageable pageable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public final List<Foo> findAll(final Sort sort) {
        return fooRepo.findAll(sort);
    }

}
```

What is the best way of testing with JUnit drivers and services to cover all logical conditions?
I always end up with a bunch of test lines to cover all logical conditions.

We recommend using MockitoJUnitRunner? Or create classes which create configuration beans. And charge them with ContextConfiguration `'ContextConfiguration (FooServiceImplTestConfiguration.class classes = {})'`

How to implement the Given-When-Then pattern?

Comment: "Best" way is pretty broad.  There are a lot of things that you could test with this resource in a lot of different ways, and no one way is the overall *best* way.

Comment: " to cover all logical conditions" is to ask for comprehensive testing, which is impractical for realistic code.

Comment: What do you want to test? The Java code in your controllers? The Java code in your service layer? The @RequestMapping? The message converters used? If you want to test all of them, this question is too broad. If you want to test only one this question is unclear.

Comment: Don't add your solution to your question; post it separately as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally I use this solution.**

For my Domain Model I use this link http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/09/tips-for-unit-testing-javabeans.html

```
/**
 * @param <T>
 */
public abstract class AbstractJavaBeanTest<T> {

    protected String[] propertiesToBeIgnored;


    protected abstract T getBeanInstance();

    @Test
    public void beanIsSerializable() throws Exception {
        final T myBean = getBeanInstance();
        final byte[] serializedMyBean = SerializationUtils.serialize((Serializable) myBean);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final T deserializedMyBean = (T) SerializationUtils.deserialize(serializedMyBean);
        assertEquals(myBean, deserializedMyBean);
    }


    @Test
    public void equalsAndHashCodeContract() {
        EqualsVerifier.forClass(getBeanInstance().getClass()).suppress(Warning.STRICT_INHERITANCE, Warning.NONFINAL_FIELDS).verify();
    }


    @Test
    public void getterAndSetterCorrectness() throws Exception {
        final BeanTester beanTester = new BeanTester();
        beanTester.getFactoryCollection().addFactory(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeFactory());
        beanTester.testBean(getBeanInstance().getClass());
    }

    class LocalDateTimeFactory implements Factory {
        @Override
        public LocalDateTime create() {
            return LocalDateTime.now();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Test Foo
 */
public class FooTest extends AbstractJavaBeanTest<Foo> {

    @Override
    protected Foo getBeanInstance() {
        return new Foo();
    }

}
```

I add this dependencies to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>nl.jqno.equalsverifier</groupId>
    <artifactId>equalsverifier</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.meanbean</groupId>
    <artifactId>meanbean</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

For my MVC controllers I use this link http://www.luckyryan.com/2013/08/24/unit-test-controllers-spring-mvc-test/

```
/**
 * Test FooController
 */
public class FooControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private FooService fooService;

    @InjectMocks
    private FooController fooController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        // Process mock annotations
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        // Setup Spring test in standalone mode
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(fooController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdd() throws Exception {

        Foo foo = new Foo();

        // given
        given(FooService.createFoo()).willReturn(foo);

        // when
        // then
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/foo/new"))
            .andExpect(forwardedUrl("foo/detail"))
            .andExpect(model().attributeExists("foo"))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("foo", is(foo)));
    }

    @Test
    public void testDetail() throws Exception {

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Long fooId = 1L;

        // given
        given(fooService.findById(fooId)).willReturn(foo);

        // when
        // then
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/foo/" + fooId))
            .andExpect(forwardedUrl("foo/detail"))
            .andExpect(view().name("foo/detail"))
            .andExpect(model().attributeExists("foo"))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("foo", is(foo)));
    }

    @Test
    public void testSave() throws Exception {

        Foo foo = new Foo();

        // given
        // when
        // then

        //With form errors
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/foo/update")
                .param("name", "")
                .sessionAttr("foo", foo))
        .andExpect(forwardedUrl("foo/detail"))
        .andExpect(model().hasErrors())
        .andExpect(model().attributeHasFieldErrors("foo", "name"));

        //Without form errores
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/foo/update")
                .param("name", "nameValue")
                .param("code", "codeValue")
                .param("date", "20/10/2015")
                .requestAttr("referer", "/foo/list")
                .sessionAttr("foo", foo))
        .andExpect(view().name("redirect:" + "/foo/list"))
        .andExpect(model().hasNoErrors())
        .andExpect(flash().attributeExists("message"))
        .andExpect(flash().attribute("message", hasProperty("message", is("message.ok"))))
        .andExpect(flash().attribute("message", hasProperty("type", is(Message.Type.SUCCESS))))
        .andExpect(status().isFound());
    }

    @Test
    public void testDelete() throws Exception {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setOtherFoos(new ArrayList<OtherFoo>());
        Long fooId = 1L;

        // given
        given(fooService.findByIdWithOtherFoos(fooId)).willReturn(foo);

        // when
        // then
        //Without errors: without other foos
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/foo/delete/" + fooId)
                .sessionAttr("foo", foo)
                .requestAttr("referer", "/foo/list"))
        .andExpect(view().name("redirect:" + "/foo/list"))
        .andExpect(flash().attributeExists("message"))
        .andExpect(flash().attribute("message", hasProperty("message", is("message.ok"))))
        .andExpect(flash().attribute("message", hasProperty("type", is(Message.Type.SUCCESS))));


        // given
        foo.getOtherFoos().add(new OtherFoo());
        given(fooService.findByIdWithOtherFoos(fooId)).willReturn(foo);

        // when
        // then
        //With errors: with other foos
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/foo/delete/" + fooId)
                .sessionAttr("foo", foo)
                .requestAttr("referer", "/foo/list"))
        .andExpect(view().name("redirect:" + "/foo/list"))
        .andExpect(flash().attributeExists("message"))
        .andExpect(flash().attribute("message", hasProperty("message", is("message.error"))))
        .andExpect(flash().attribute("message", hasProperty("type", is(Message.Type.DANGER))));
    }

}
```

For my JUnit service test I implemented a class for Configuration and I load it in the service test

```
@Configuration
public class FooServiceImplTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public FooService fooService() {
        return new FooServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public FooRepository fooRepository() {
        return Mockito.mock(FooRepository.class);
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {FooServiceImplTestConfiguration.class})
public class FooServiceImplTest {

    @Inject
    private FooRepository fooRepository;;

    @Inject
    private FooService fooService;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void oneTimeSetUp() {
        // one-time initialization code
        System.out.println("@BeforeClass - oneTimeSetUp");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void oneTimeTearDown() {
        // one-time cleanup code
        System.out.println("@AfterClass - oneTimeTearDown");
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    @Test
    public void createFoo() {
        assertNotNull(fooService.createFoo());
    }

    @Test
    public void save() {

        //New foo
        Foo saveFoo = new Foo();
        // given

        // when
        fooService.save(saveFoo);

        // then
        assertNotNull(saveFoo.getDate());

        saveFoo.setId(1L);
        Date date = new Date();
        saveFoo.setDate(date);

        // given

        //when
        fooService.save(saveFoo);

        //then
        assertThat(date, is(saveFoo.getDate()));
    }

    @Test
    public void delete() {

        //given

        //when
        fooService.deleteFoo(Matchers.anyLong());

        //then
    }

    @Test
    public void findById() {
        Long id = 1L;
        Foo fooResult = new Foo();

        //given
        given(fooRepository.findOne(id)).willReturn(fooResult);

        //when
        Foo foo = fooService.findById(id);

        //then
        assertThat(foo, is(fooResult));
    }

    @Test
    public void findByIdWithOtherFoos() {
        Long id = 1L;
        Foo fooResult = new Foo();

        //given
        given(fooRepository.findOne(id)).willReturn(fooResult);

        //when
        Foo foo = fooService.findByIdWithOtherFoos(id);

        //then
        assertThat(foo, is(fooResult));
    }

    @Test
    public void findAll() {
        Page<Foo> fooResult = new PageImpl<>(new ArrayList<Foo>());

        given(fooRepository.findAll(Matchers.<Pageable>anyObject())).willReturn(fooResult);

        //when
        Page<Foo> foos = fooService.findAll(Matchers.<Pageable>anyObject());

        //then
        assertThat(foos, is(fooResult));
    }

    @Test
    public void findAllList() {
        List<Foo> fooResult = new ArrayList<Foo>();

        given(fooRepository.findAll(Matchers.<Sort>anyObject())).willReturn(fooResult);

        //when
        List<Foo> foos = fooService.findAll(Matchers.<Sort>anyObject());

        //then
        assertThat(foos, is(fooResult));
    }
}
```

In my pom I need add this dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- This is for mocking the service -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Optional -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I need change the my hibernate validator version for this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I need add this dependencies too because I got this excecption:

Cause: java.lang.AbstractMethodError:org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;

Detail message: org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm using spring data, I need to do the test for my custom CrudRepositories too.

Answer (score 5):

When it comes to testing Controllers (especially integration testing) i suggest using [Spring's MockMVC](http://www.luckyryan.com/2013/08/24/unit-test-controllers-spring-mvc-test/) or [Rest-Assured](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured). And example of using Rest-Assured in action can be seen below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SomeApplication.class)
@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort = true)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public class SomeControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void getAllSomeObjects() {
        expect().statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK)
                .body("", hasSize(2))
                .body("[0]", notNullValue())
                .body("[1]", notNullValue())
                .body("findAll { it.name.equals('TEST1') }", hasSize(1))
                .body("findAll { it.name.equals('TEST2') }", hasSize(1))
                .when()
                .get("/someAddress");
    }
}
```

For testing Services i suggest using [Mockito](http://mockito.org/). Additionally [Hamcrest Matchers](http://hamcrest.org/) is a useful library for assertions in tests. Example of using both below:

```
public class SomeServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private SomeService someService;

    @Mock
    private SomeInnerService someInnerService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        initMocks(this);
        Mockito.when(someInnerService.useMethod("argument")).thenReturn(new SomeObject());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() {
        Set<SomeObject> someObjects= someService.someMethod();
        assertThat(someObjects, is(notNullValue()));
        assertThat(someObjects, is(hasSize(4)));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should test both independently.

First create a unit test for your service. You can use Mockito to mock your service dependency as fooRepository.

```
@Test
public void testFindById() {
    when(fooServices.findById(123)).thenReturn(fooSample);
    assertThat(what you want);
}
```

Then, you should create an other unit test for your controller. The easiest way to do that is to use [MockMvc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html) provided in spring-test. And in this case, you can use Mockito to mock fooService.

Answer (score 2):

Best Part. Use spring MVC test layer. As they are providing their own API's which helps you to mock controllers and provide you session objects which you can fill with required state. you can find lots of examples online.
http://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-mvc-test-tutorial/
You can actually test all your layers seperately .. All the best !!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Spring-Test-MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework). That's a framework for exactly that purpose and comes with a lot of easy to understand and rebuild examples.

Personally I add Mockito / PowerMock to the mix for mocking internal dependencies away.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of test you want to implement.

Certainly [Spring Test](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testing) helps in this. This module supports "unit" and integration testing. Note that unit tests are not really true unit tests because there is a little bit of context loading involved while using Spring Test at it's minimum.

Check the [MockMvc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html) class that you can use to make requests to controllers.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use `ContextConfiguration` in combination with `DirtiesContext`, `MockMvcBuilders` and Mockito. This gives you the advantage of creating a Spring controller through an application context and injecting beans whose behaviour is defined through Mockito. In this case you can reach high line and condition coverage. Here is an example for your code:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class FooControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private FooService service;

    @Autowired
    private FooController controller;

    @Before
    public void initController() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(frontEndController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDoSomeThing_CornerCase() {
        // Given: 
        // define the behaviour of service with when(service...)

        // Then:
        // perform a request on contoller
        mockMvc.perform(get("/foo/delete/{id}"))

        // When:
        // user Mockito verify 
        // or
        // MockMvcRequestBuilders
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class FooConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public FooController controller() {
            return new FooController();
        }

        @Bean
        public FooService service() {
            return mock(FooService.class);
        }

    }
}
```

`DirtiesContext` is important so that you get clean mocks a every test.

Comment: I use this way but I have a exception to initialize the mockMvc. I edit the question with tutorial link